# Issues when I try to login in to AWS CLI using a Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync a file between a Docker container to an AWS Bucket, but I´m having issues when I´m trying to log in or run the first parameters. I´m constantly getting this message:

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
> [parameters] To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help   aws  help   aws   help
>
> aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong in my file. This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster
COPY ./target/AWS-Writer-Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar AWS-Writer-Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","AWS-Writer-Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

FROM amazon/aws-cli
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_REGION

RUN aws ecr get-login-password --no-include-email | bash
RUN aws s3 cp s3://AWS-Writer-Test/logs/log.txt /log.txt --recursive

#ENTRYPOINT [ "aws", "ecr get-login-password --no-include-email | bash" ]
```

Any idea what could be my mistake? Thanks for your support.

**P.S.:**

- The final goal is to sync the **log files from the Docker Container to the S3 Bucket**.
- This is **not a public image**. The info is going to be stored in a private repo, inaccessible from the Internet, only accessible through the Intranet. However, I´m planning to use some secrets in AWS later, but first I have to make it work.

Comment: This approach copies your AWS credentials into the image, where someone could later extract and reuse them (running cryptocurrency miners on your dime).  I'd run the `aws` commands outside Docker, and just `COPY` the file into the image.

Comment: Which command throws the error?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I just want to test if it works locally first :). Could you give me some hints? I will move them later to some secrets.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I just run it and threw me that message.

Comment: Also @DavidMaze, I need to copy the logs file that is inside the jar from there to S3.

Comment: I don't think the Dockerfile is the right place to do that.  Think of its output like a `.jar` file that you could run later.

Comment: Hi, @DavidMaze thanks for your comment. I agree that´s why I plan to use some secrets for production. However, first and foremost I should make it work. This is not even the real app, but the first step, and I should sync two folders.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the difference between the two syntax versions which are described in the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint.

You have actually a mixture of both of them.

> ENTRYPOINT has two forms:
>
> The exec form, which is the preferred form:
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
> The shell form:
>
> ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2

Your `ENTRYPOINT` is `[ "aws", "ecr get-login-password --no-include-email | bash" ]`
so it runs directly (probably with something like [execve()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) aws command without any *shell* (that is important) and it tries to feed aws with just one parameter and that is everything together `ecr get-login-password --no-include-email | bash`.

The correct syntax would be
`["aws","ecr","get-login-password","--no-include-email"]`. The rest of it:

`| bash`, particularly the `'|'` pipe symbol has no meaning, because it is a *shell* expression. And you decided to run no shell (by choosing the first version of the `ENTRYPOINT` syntax), so you cannot use any shell commands/expressions like `if` for example.

If you need to use the shell, then you need to run the shell version of the ENTRYPOINT, so your syntax would be:

`ENTRYPOINT aws ecr get-login-password --no-include-email | bash`

I would suggest to you to try all three versions and see the difference among the error messages (or the lack of them).